# Cannot generate buffers in meters (even after "save as" in NAD83 / UTM 18N) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, utm

I am quite new to GIS and QGIS.

I have 800 points with lat/lon (some locations in Massachusetts) in a .csv file. I use `AddLayer` to import the CSV file and save it as NAD83 / UTM 18N projection (EPSG:26918). Then I close QGIS and reopen the new 26918 file with QGIS. I want to create buffer for the points, and I want 500 meters as the buffer radius. I use `Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffer`, and I entered 500 in the field for "Buffer Distance" and saved the new shapefile. Then the following pictures shows... I wonder how can I make such a buffer with 500m radius for the points?

[image]

---

The problem is that the buffer is way larger than 500 m (probably 500 degrees). I have figure out how to deal with it: after adding the csv file as a layer, I should first saving it in the WGS84 projection. And then save the WGS84 layer as a NAD83 / UTM 18N layer. Then I can create 500 m radius buffer.

Comment: I don't see where your problem is. You might increase the number of segments to get a nice circle, but otherwise it looks good. What do you get if you measure the diameter? What picture did you expect? A buffer around a polygon around all points?

Comment: What can we see on the screenshot? The extent of the buffer layer? Did you try to measure the radius of the circle with the Measure tool?

Comment: Do you mean you buffer has not a radius of 500m?

Comment: I suspect the buffer is trying to do a width of 500 *degrees* which is obviously nonsense - hard to be sure since your image doesn't have any context. Try using "Fixed Distance Buffer" from the Geoprocessing Toolbox instead of the drop-down menu...

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear. Yes, the problem is that the buffer is way larger than 500 m (probably 500 degrees). I have figure out how to deal with it: after adding the csv file as a layer, I should first saving it in the WGS84 projection. And then save the WGS84 layer as a NAD83 / UTM 18N layer. Then I can create 500 m radius buffer. Thanks for all the answers!